# Implementing celery messed up my INSTALLED_APPS (ModuleNotFoundError: No module named myapp)

Tags: python-3.x, django-rest-framework, celery

I think there are may be similar questions to this one, but not  quite the same so this is why I'm posting this. Basically my Djang Rest Framework was working fine, then I tried implementing celery and now it's messed up my imports, and seems to be throwing an error message after initiating a celery worker. I'm on Windows 10.

**Project structure**

```
- MyProj
  -> MyProj (same name)
    -> __init__.py
    -> celery_tasks.py
    -> settings.py
  - MyApp
    -> __init__.py
    -> load_of_other_files
```

**init.py**

```
#from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
from MyProj.celery_tasks import app as celery_app

__all__ = ('celery_app',)
```

**celery_tasks.py**

```
#from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
import os
from celery import Celery
import time

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "settings")
app = Celery("tasks", broker="amqp://localhost//", backend="rpc://")
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')
app.autodiscover_tasks()
```

**settings.py**

```
import os
..
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
    'MyApp',
]
```

Then I cd into my `MyProj` directory and trigger a worker like so:

```
celery -A celery_tasks worker --loglevel=INFO --concurrency=10 -n worker1.%h --pool=solo
```

The  traceback I receive is:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'MyApp'
```

I've tried with and without the `from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals` but doesn't  seem to work. I understand that the absolute_import  is necessary to avoid  the celery.py conflict with the celery library, which in my case is not the case, because my celery.py is called celery_tasks.py (to avoid confusion). How can I bypass this error message?

Comment: Have you tried to put an `__init__.py` file in your root folder `MyProj`. I doubt this has anything to do with celery itself.

Comment: @loicgasser: yes, didn't  work. I think too it may have more to do with the project structure

Comment: is your issue resolved? I have exactly same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error win10, Django and celery 5.0.5. I overcame this by modifying the `app.autodiscover_tasks()` within the celery.py file.  In my case, the

```
 app = Celery('project',
                 broker='amqp://',
                 backend='rpc://',
              #  include=['project.tasks'] ### project.tasks not found
    )
```

did not resolve, but when I specified the Django modules which contain the tasks.py files i.e. `app.autodiscover_tasks(['parm','demoapp']),` the ModuleNotFoundError: was resolved.